# MySQL: selecting data not in common between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table1 with 3 numbers and table2 with 1 number:

```
table1       table2
n              n
1              1
2
3
```

I want to select data from table1 that is NOT present in table2 (numbes 2 and 3). I tried:

```
select table1.* from table1, table2 where table1.n <> table2.n
```

I also tried other where clauses:

```
where table1.n not like table2.n
where not table1.n = table2.n
```

But I don't get the results. I know it can be done in multiple steps, but I wonder if there is a simple query to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a LEFT JOIN and look for null values for t2.  Like this:

```
SELECT
   t1.n
FROM
   table1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
     ON t1.n = t2.n
WHERE
    t2.n IS NULL
```

Here is link to a great reference for different sorts of JOINS which includes Venn diagrams to help you visualize the different approaches to joining.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: your answer is better than the other answer using NOT IN() because NOT IN() runs two separate queries and does a check from one query to the other.. when you have really large tables it slows a lot because of the additional checks.

Comment: the where t2.n IS NULL is the best way to do it because it just pulls out the data and then checks to see where its null... not running a second query potentially thousands of times

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using NOT IN or NOT EXISTS.

```
select * from table1
where table1.n not in (select table2.n from table2);

select * from table1
where  not exists (select table2.n from table2 where table2.n = table1.n);
```

Comment: This is a problematic approach.  If both tables are small, or if table2 is small, this may be OK, but if table 2 is large, this can become a very slow query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both approaches (left join and not in) several times and it took the exact same time (my table is pretty big). Thanks guys!